# concatenate audio files with an image

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to concatenate multiple audio files and a single image into one video file using one command.
I have list of mp3 files and a playlist file (.m3u) in a direcotry.

I managed to do this but my solution is bad:

1. reading the playlist file and creating a new .txt in the ffmpeg required format
2. concatenating the audio files using the .txt into an .mp3
3. concatenating the large audio file and the static image into a video

This creates 2 unnecessary files that I have to delete.

---

I tried a different command

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i myImage.jpg -i file1.mp3 -i file2.mp3 -i file3.mp3 -filter_complex '[0:0][1:0][2:0]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1' -tune stillimage -shortest output.mp4
```

however im getting a `Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument` error

Another kick in the nuts is that the system im working on has spaces in the folder names.
i tried using -i "concat:file1.mp3|file2.mp3|..." however i cannot use double quote marks to quote out the path so I get an invalid argument error.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Method 1: [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat)

Make `input.txt` containing the following:

```
file 'file1.mp3'
file 'file2.mp3'
file 'file3.mp3'
```

Run `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i myImage.jpg -f concat -i input.txt -filter_complex "[0]scale='iw-mod(iw,2)':'ih-mod(ih,2)',format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -r 15 -tune stillimage -map 1:a -shortest -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

All MP3 files being input to the concat demuxer must have the same channel layout and sample rate. If they do not then convert them using the `-ac` and `-ar` options so they are all the same.

---

## Method 2: [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat)

**Update:** There seems to be a bug with `-shortest` not working with the concat filter (I keep forgetting about that). See the method above using the concat demuxer, or replace `-shortest` with `-t`. The value for `-t` should equal the total duration of all three MP3 files.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i myImage.jpg -i file1.mp3 -i file2.mp3 -i file3.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]scale='iw-mod(iw,2)':'ih-mod(ih,2)',format=yuv420p[v];[1:a][2:a][3:a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[a]" -map "[v]" -r 15 -map "[a]" -tune stillimage -shortest -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

---

### Option descriptions

- [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filter makes image have even width and height which is required when outputting YUV 4:2:0 with libx264.
- [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) filter sets chroma subsampling to 4:2:0, otherwise libx264 will try to limit subsampling, but most players can only handle 4:2:0.
- [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filter is accepting `file1.mp3`, `file2.mp3`, and `file3.mp3` as inputs. Your original command was trying to concat the video to the audio resulting in `Invalid argument`.
- `-map "[v]"` chooses the video output from `-filter_complex`.
- `-r 15` sets output frame rate to 15 because most players can't handle 1 fps. This is faster than setting `-framerate 15`.
- `-map "[a]"` chooses the audio output from `-filter_complex`.
- `-map 1:a` chooses the audio from input #1 (the second input as counting starts from 0).
- `-movflags +faststart` after encoding finishes this option moves some data from the end of the MP4 output file to the beginning. This allows playback to begin faster otherwise the complete file will have to be downloaded first.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what that's doing? Or a source explaining each arg - I'm curious.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much @llogan. It almost works, the command doesn't stop running when the audio has finished, so it keeps generating video frames with no sound.

Comment: I have a large collection of audio files (with playlists grouping them together) that I need to concatenate and upload to youtube. The issue is that youtube doesent accept audio files so I need to concatenate all the relevant audio files and then add an image to convert it into a video.

Comment: @RomanKubiv "Method 1: concat demuxer" should do that.